# How to freeze / block columns?

Tags: slickgrid

Can I freeze columns when scrolling horizontally?

More exactly these columns should be fixed when scrolling.

Comment: Yes, you could... I have just added a nice implementation of this to the slick.grid version with good performance compromise

Comment: Check https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/208

Answer (score 0):

I think a cloned grid can be added that resides on the left showing only the columns that are required to be frozen. Since it's going to be the same grid all the events will be available on the cloned grid also.

Answer (score 0):

@jlynch7 has the most robust implementation of frozen columns that I've found. You can see a working example here: http://jlynch7.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-frozen-columns.html